# Vice Versa Of friendship(accessibility) in class is true or not In C++?

Tags: c++, friend-class

A friend class can access the members of the class containing the friend function. Is Its vice-versa i.e. the class can also access the members of it friend class is true?

Comment: No.  That would make access modifiers pointless as you could just make yourself a friend of a class.

Comment: I want to ask why they have mark this as negative?

Comment: Someone actually understood the question? I didn't.

Comment: You could write a few lines of code to check this yourself.

Comment: Some good info: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends#friendship-not-inherited-transitive

Comment: @LogicStuff I believe OP is asking if you have `class A{ friend B; };` can `A` access `B`'s private members

Comment: @Gaurav _"I want to ask why they have mark this as negative?"_ Extremely low research efforts shown probably.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I have searched this on google and I have also read the sections of Complete reference C++. But I didn't get my answer

Comment: @Gaurav: Hover over the downvote button

Comment: [Ryan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1013719/ryan-haining)  I wasn't talking about just B's private variable but any variables.

Comment: @Gaurav it can already access `B`'s public variables. private would imply protected to in this case. What do you mean by "*any*" variables?

Comment: @Gaurav OT to ping people use the `@` syntax in comments.

Comment: @RyanHaining: Variables of type `std::any<T>` for some `T`, of course!

Comment: General advice, @Gaurav: read the documentation for tools that you use. That means C++, Stack Overflow and anything else. Read it before you use them. Thanks.

Comment: @RyanHaining Sorry. I am just a beginner. I forgot. I was talking about private and protected.Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @Gaurav is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e626aaf5b9890e06) what you're asking about?

Comment: @RyanHaining Thats the exact thing I am talking about.

Comment: @Gaurav well, as you can see, it is unidirectional and that example doesn't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Its vice-versa i.e. the class can also access the members of it friend class is true?

No, they can't. The `friend` keyword is unidirectional.

---

To provide `friend` functionality in a bidirectional way, you have to specify both classes as `friend` for each other. This actually requires a forward declaration of at least one of these candidate classes:

```
class B; // Forward declare
class A {
    friend class B;
};

class B {
    friend class A;
};
```

Comment: So, its only true in mutual friendship?

Comment: @Gaurav What do you mean _mutual friendship_? Declaring as `friend` at both sides?

Comment: yes like      class A {
                           friend class B;
                         };

              class B {
             friend class A;
                   };  I'm sorry. I am not able to intend it correctly

Comment: @Gaurav That needs a forward declaration (of at least `class B;`), without that you're ending up in _circular_.

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide a link. I am just a beginner.

Comment: nit: I'd recommend `friend A;` and `friend B;` to avoid accidentally forward declaring a class with a different name

Comment: Thanks for well explaining all.